# \part and \thispagestyle{empty}

Tags: formatting

I have a Part page in my document where I want to hide the page number. I am using:

```
\part{Beginning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

on the Part document.

However, the page number still appears. I've tried typesetting the main document that inputs the Part child document a number of times with no effect.

Any help with such a trivial problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be much better if you provided a compilable example starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. That way it's much easier to help.

Comment: Try using `\cleardoublepage
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\part{Beginning}
\endgroup`

Comment: Thanks Werner - BRILLIANT! Works like a dream - no more head banging for now, thanks.

Comment: @Mike Should be be using a KOMA-Script class (`scrbook`, `scrreprt`, ...) place `\renewcommand*\partpagestyle{empty}` in your preamble.

Comment: (in other words: we *always* need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) because the right answer depends...)

Answer (score 10):

`\part` is usually defined in the document class.

## Class `article`

`\thispagestyle{empty}` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\part{Beginning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

## Classes `report` and `book`

Class `book` (similar `report`) defines `\part` the following way:

```
\newcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  ...
  \secdef\@part\@spart
}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  ... % part title
  \@endpart
}
\def\@spart#1{%
  ... % part title
  \@endpart
}
\def\@endpart{%
  \vfil
  \newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  ...
}
```

After the setting of the part title with `\thispagestyle{plain}` in force,
`\@endpart` is called that starts new page. At least a following empty page will have page style `empty`.

Therefore `\thispagestyle{empty}` comes too late, `\part{...}` has already generated one or two pages.

As workaround the [trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191181/part-and-thispagestyleempty#comment440841_191181) of Werner can be used:

```
\cleardoublepage
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \part{Beginning}
\endgroup
```

Or `\part` can be patched to replace `\thispagestyle{plain}` by `\thispagestyle{empty}`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\part}}

\begin{document}
\part{Beginning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

## Class [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir)

A comfortable package with many setup options. Also the page style for `\part` can be configured:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}

\begin{document}
\part{Beginning}
\end{document}
```

## Class `scrartcl` ([KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script))

Same case as class `article` (the part title does not cover the whole page, but the top part only):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\part{Beginning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

## Classes `scrreprt` and `scrbook` ([KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script))

Also these classes are comfortable, because the page style for part pages can be configured. Macro `\partpagestyle` is used as page style name, which can be redefined (see the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191181/part-and-thispagestyleempty#comment440846_191181) of cgnieder):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}
\part{Beginning}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! OK I now need time to work my way through this and see how they work rather than simply copying and pasting code into my document. I'm interested in understanding how things work, and why.

Comment: Is it possible to include a graphic to the lower half of the page given that \partpagestyle{empty} clears the whole page?

Comment: @Mike: Again it depends on the document class, how "easy" it is. For example, if class `memoir` is used, `\afterpartskip` could be redefined to add the image. In KOMA-Script the command name would be `\partheadendvskip`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `titlesec` package, that comes with `titleps` ( a replacement for `fancyhdr`), the `clearempty` option  suppresses page numbers on empty pages.